# python regex to extract only specific pattern file names from a list

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I would like to extract only certain files from a list. I need to apply following rules while extracting only selected files from a list.

if the file contains patterns like **f[1-99]** or **t[1-99]** or **v[1-99]** or combination of **f[1-9]_v[1-9]_t[1-9]**. below are some sample.

```
phone_football_androind_1_v1_te_t1_fe
phone_football_ios_v1_t1
foot_cricket2345678_f12_t4
tfd_fr_ve_t1_v1_f3_201234_yyymmmdd
def_000_t4_f1
file_job_1234567_f1_t55
ROKLOP_f33_t44
agdcv_t45
gop_gop_f1_t14_v14
file_op_v1_t1
fop_f1_v1_1223
```

could u lease help how to check if the above patterns contains in the files and take only file with following patterns? I have tried following but stuck with reges in python. not sure how to add OR condition in regex

```
import re

# Take input from users
MyString1 = "tfd_fr_ve_t1_v1_f3_201234_yyymmmdd"

# re.search() returns a Match object
# if there is a match anywhere in the string
if re.search('(_v(\d+)).*', MyString1):
    print("YES,it is present in string ")
else:
    print("NO,string is not present")
```

Comment: While I could write a comment on how to do this, a better option would be to visit https://regex101.com/ and select Python mode on the left. Is a great way to try out regular expressions and see what they do.

Comment: Do you expect to match `f2_t6_v8`, `v6_f9_t6`, or any such combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a match is present:

```
_[ftv][1-9]\d?(?!\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `_` Match literally
- `[ftv]` Match one of `f` `t` `v`
- `[1-9]\d?` Match a digit 1- 99
- `(?!\d)` Assert not a digit to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KjCg8O/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iVRLKO)

Example code

```
import re

strings = [
    "tfd_fr_ve_t1_v1_f3_201234_yyymmmdd",
    "phone_football_androind_1_v1_te_t1_fe",
    "phone_football_ios_v1_t1",
    "foot_cricket2345678_f12_t4",
    "tfd_fr_ve_t1_v1_f3_201234_yyymmmdd",
    "def_000_t4_f1",
    "file_job_1234567_f1_t55",
    "ROKLOP_f33_t44",
    "agdcv_t45",
    "gop_gop_f1_t14_v14",
    "file_op_v1_t1",
    "fop_f1_v1_1223",
    "test"
]
pattern = r"_[ftv][1-9]\d?(?!\d)"
for s in strings:
    if re.search(pattern, s):
        print(f"YES, present in '{s}' ")
    else:
        print(f"NO, not present in '{s}'")
```

Output

```
YES, present in 'tfd_fr_ve_t1_v1_f3_201234_yyymmmdd' 
YES, present in 'phone_football_androind_1_v1_te_t1_fe' 
YES, present in 'phone_football_ios_v1_t1' 
YES, present in 'foot_cricket2345678_f12_t4' 
YES, present in 'tfd_fr_ve_t1_v1_f3_201234_yyymmmdd' 
YES, present in 'def_000_t4_f1' 
YES, present in 'file_job_1234567_f1_t55' 
YES, present in 'ROKLOP_f33_t44' 
YES, present in 'agdcv_t45' 
YES, present in 'gop_gop_f1_t14_v14' 
YES, present in 'file_op_v1_t1' 
YES, present in 'fop_f1_v1_1223' 
NO, not present in 'test'
```